# Using angular-js ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this requirement where i need to disable a button based on some condition:

Controller:

```
<div  ng-controller= "myController" class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"   aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"> Add</h4>
```

I need to disable this button when I have added 5 entries in html page.Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array of that items, assume that the array is called `items`, you can pass a condition to the `ng-disabled` to set to true if the `items.length >= 5`.

```
<button type="button" class="close" ng-disabled="items.length >= 5" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >×</button>
```

Comment: Can i call a function within ng-disabled?

Comment: Yes you can. It gets an expression inside

Answer (score 0):

When Entries Length is 5

```
<button ng-disabled="entries.length == 5"></button>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and the answer below?

Comment: Where is your answer @jitender

Comment: Bro I don't answer just see answer given by @suren below 5 min ago than your answer

Answer (score 0):

if your value or the entires is array then you can do as follows

```
    <div  ng-controller= "myController" class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"   aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"> Add</h4>
<button ng-disabled="entries.length >= 5">ADD</button>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and the answer below?

Comment: I dont see your answer anywhere @jitender

Comment: am never say answer by me i said answer below check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/46461100/5621827

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
    <div ng-controller="myController" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-disabled="isButtonDisabled()">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"> Add</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And at controller

```
$scope.isButtonDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.requiredArray.length >= 5;
}
```

This function will check whether the length of the required array is greater than 5 or not. If true button will be disabled.